# trying a custom chart setup or software

Tags: python, charts

[question_set_custom_charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0wbg.jpg)

how can i make this information as charts , i have few prices which i will add each day in column and below it there will be volume for entire day and arrow as direction .

i know python. can anyone tell me how can i do this

i tried searching for similar problems using python not got a helpful though i did it in excel it worked but the issue is with the keeping information for each item as well i need to put everything [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpczU.png)

as can see in excel this type of stuff i want to do , but i dont know which tool to use if i want to do with python

Comment: _i know python_ Then show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: re read it bro i did it in excel, but myself want to know how should i approach for this using python . i dont want others code or anything yet instead few suggestions what resources to learn as i will be doing this type of projects a lot

Comment: "Please write this code for me" is not a question.

Comment: i think my question and intention both have been misunderstood,

Comment: i have put my idea and implemented in excel as i posted two pics above, second i know python but i dont know the approach i should be taking for this problem.

Comment: This is not an advice/guidance forum.  You should at least know enough to ask a **specific** programming question.  If you really don't even know where to start, you might want to look elsewhere for help.

Comment: i didnt tag u specifically for to answer if u got any issue simply ignore if anyone would be knowing it they may put an answer and if it against the community for posting this type of question then go ahead ban me .